# action geo:GetPlace not recognizable for IAM policy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, geolocation, location

currently working on an app that uses the Amazon Location Service.

Everything is working wwll from render map to autocomplete and reverse geocoding.

But i would like to use the results from autocomplete by using the method geo:GetPlace using PlaceIndex and PlaceID. The function is being called successfully with the correct parameters but the function is returning an err 403 saying that the user is not authorized to use action geo:GetPlace. I have configured the IAM policy using Cognito and has appropriate actions and resources. But when i try to enter geo:GetPlace i get an error that it is not recognizable. Anyone knows how to enter this action to the IAM Policy.

Here is the error:

AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::58*******976:assumed-role/Cognito_*************Management_***/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: geo:GetPlace on resource: arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:58*****65976:*

Here is my code:

```
    const identityPoolId = "ap-southeast-1:*******-6dcb-***-ad06-*******";      

    AWS.config.region = identityPoolId.split(":")[0];
          // instantiate an Amazon Cognito-backed credential provider
      const credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
      });
    
      const location = new AWS.Location({ credentials, region: AWS.config.region });

 

     const getLocation = (placeID) => () => {
        console.log("getting place..");
        console.log(placeID);
    
        let params = {
          IndexName: "IndexGrabber",
          PlaceId: placeID,
        };
    
        location.getPlace(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err.stack);
          console.log(data);
        });
      };
```

IAM Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "geo:SearchPlaceIndexForText",
                "geo:SearchPlaceIndexForSuggestions",
                "geo:GetMap*",
                "geo:SearchPlaceIndexForPosition"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:place-index/HEREGrabber",
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:place-index/LocationGrabber",
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:map/LocationGrabber",
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:map/GreyLocationGrabber",
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:map/HEREGrabber"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://localhost:*/*",
                        "http://jularbs.com:*/*",
                        "http://*******.herokuapp.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "geo:GetPlace",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:place-index/HEREGrabber",
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:place-index/LocationGrabber",
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:map/LocationGrabber",
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:map/GreyLocationGrabber",
                "arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:************:map/HEREGrabber"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://localhost:*/*",
                        "http://jularbs.com:*/*",
                        "http://*******.herokuapp.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You say you have set up the permissions properly but the error message says otherwise. And the error message is the one to believe in these cases. Therefore: show the permission you have set up.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, already edited the question to include iam policy. already tried putting the geo:GetPlace on a single statement with other actions. now i tried to segregate it within the Statement Array. still to no avail.

Comment: What comes after the `on resource: arn:aws:geo:ap-southeast-1:58*****65976:` - does that resource match any of the ones in your policy statement? Maybe GetPlace does not have a resource at all and you therefore need to replace the `Resource` block with a `*` in your second policy statement!? Interesting that geo:GetPlace is not listed at all under https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonlocation.html

Comment: @luk2302 Yes this what made me confused as GetPlace is present in all their documentations but not in their service authorization list. Thought it was still in preview but not. Regarding your question, yes it doesnt match as in my policy i listed my allowed resources but it the error stack trace it uses a wildcard indicating all resources in my account.

Comment: Then try `"Resource": "*"` for the `get:GetPlace` policy statement.

Comment: Will try this, thanks @luk2302. Also posted on Re:POST maybe can get help from there to.

Comment: This features seems to be broken as already tried Actions: "geo:*" resouces: "*", still no use.